# How to import gITF file from Nomad Sculpt into Blender with layer painting?

Tags: import, texture-painting

I am very new to Blender and I am trying to import a gITF file from Nomad Sculpt.

Heres a description of what i've done:

Export gITF 2.0 file from nomad into google drive with the following checkboxes ticked:

- Vertex colours
- PBR  paint
- Layers
- Layer painting

Downloaded said file from google drive into my computer.

Imported the gITF file into Blender and turned on viewport shading as the object was in grey. (I followed a tutorial on youtube by 'Above Wongart"

The colours showed up but only as full colours on each layer. I created a humanoid so the body was in a solid colour and the hair was a solid colour too. What's missing, is the painting/drawing I did on those layers.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated! :)

[image: humanoid]